# .Net: Why 4GB free managed memory?

Tags: .net, memory, memory-management

I have a rather big 64 bit .Net WPF application. Some users complain about the high memory footprint (6GB and more). When examining a memory dump in Jetbrains dotMemory, we see that around 1GB of .Net Managed memory is in use, but there is a total of around 5GB .Net memory reserved (.Net total is 5GB, .Net used is 1GB).

As I understand it, this is heap space reserved for quicker allocation, but I don't find good documentation about this.

The application often requires allocating a lot of memory (several hundreds MB), which is released several minutes later. But I don't it it ever needed the full 5GB, or will ever need it. Is it normal to have that much reserved heap space?

Comment: Is that a *real* problem or a *perceived* problem? Are they running out of memory or swapping? .NET applications will not "give memory back" if it's not needed for other applications. Just because it says "5GB" in task manager does not mean it's bad if there is enough free.

Comment: There is no real problem, besides the users complaining. I know the reserved space doesn't impact the user as long as there is enough free physical memory, but I want to
1. be sure there's not anything we do wrong/can do better
2. find the right documentation to explain this correctly to the user.

Comment: Having a lot of memory reserved is not the same as a process "touching" all the pages.   Until a page is touched, windows does not allocate any RAM to it.  Hence process explorer is very misleading.